# Open FileGDB Using QGIS 3 + OSX

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, osx, file-geodatabase

I'm running the latest version of QGIS 3 from [here](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download) and installed via DMG. However when I attempt to import a FileGDB, I'm not seeing the previous **ESRI FileGDB** option and the **Open FileGDB** driver doesn't seem to recognize it either.

[image]

When I attempt to drag it into the layers dialog box I get the following error message:

> Layer is not valid: The layer /Volumes/Macintosh HD/MSES6050/Geology/Formats/StanardsvilleVA.mdb is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map. Reason:

Without any further explanation of the reason. I've opened GDB files in previous version so I'm wondering if this is because of the way the DMG is compiled? Or can somehow add in this support after the fact?

Comment: `.mdb` is a **personal** geodatabase (Access). File geodatabase is a directory with a `.gdb` suffix.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by installing the ODBC Manger from Actual Technologies available [here](http://www.actualtech.com/readme.php). Importing MDB files is similar to the process described by Randal Hale [here](https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-accessing-personal-geodatabase). The primary difference is that tutorial is based on a Windows installation. On OSX you will need to buy the software to access more than three rows of data inside the database. I did purchase and can confirm this works.

Comment: Your question and answer are on different topics. Please rewrite the question and title to focus on personal geodatabase.